# Chart.JS - Polar area - Legend hover style and margin

Tags: css, chart.js

[image: polar-chart]

Hi all,

Hopefully this is an easy one. I've set up a legend with an onclick event but would like the mouse cursor to change to "pointer" when I hover over the labels (see chart screenshot above). Currently it's hard to tell that the labels are links because the mouse cursor doesn't change when I hover over them.

Also how do I add some margin/padding between the legend and chart (space below the legend).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior using a combination of the [legend onHover config option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration) (to change the pointer style to `pointer`) and the [custom tooltips config option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-external-tooltips) (to change the pointer style back to `default`).

Here is an example config demonstrating a working solution.  I wasn't sure if you were using jQuery or not so I decided not to use it.  Feel free to change accordingly.

```
options: {
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
    labels: {
      fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    },
    onHover: function(event, legendItem) {
      document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = 'pointer';
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    custom: function(tooltip) {
      if (!tooltip.opacity) {
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = 'default';
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Works perfectly...do you also know how I can get a space (padding / margin) between the chart and legend?

Comment: Unfortunately, there really isn't a way to add more space between the auto-generated legend and the chart.  You can of course change the placement of the legend, however if you truly want to control here its located and how much space is between stuff then you should go with your own custom legend using the `.generateLegend()` prototype method.  Search SO, there are plenty of questions demonstrating how this is done.

Comment: hmmm ok, maybe I'll come back to it another time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @HDhani It turns out it is possible with the default legend.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585861/chart-js-increase-spacing-between-legend-and-chart/42589310) that I posted earlier today.

Comment: wow that's a lot of code just to add some spacing... but works perfectly!! Genius :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found a different way to make this work. This lines up more literally in my mind. Perhaps the framework was updated in the interim since this was initially answered.

```
 // This event fires anytime you mouse over the chart canvas.
onHover: function (event) {
    event.target.style.cursor = 'default';
},
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    onHover: function (event, legendItem) {
        // There is only a legendItem when your mouse is positioned over one
        if (legendItem) {
            event.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        }
    }
}
```

In case anyone wants to know more, here are the docs for [events](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html#event-option) and the [legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html).

Comment: "event.srcElement.style.cursor" is deprecated. use "event.target.style.cursor" instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

Faster, without scanning the DOM every time, you find the target under **native** in the hover event

Tested in version **3.2.1** and **3.3.2** (latest on 2021 jun 22)

```
options: {
  plugins : {
    legend: {   
      labels: {
        onHover: function (e) {
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        },
        onLeave: function (e) {
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me because my tooltips are always visible (`position: "nearest"`). So I use a timeout to change and revert the cursor style:

```
onHover: function(event, legendItem) {
    document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "pointer";
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // global var
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "default";
    }, 100);
}
```

It's a dirty trick but it works.