# Chart.js - show tooltip when hovering on legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I recently upgraded my version of Chart.js from `v2.3` to `v2.7.1`, which broke an existing functionality where the specified segment in a doughnut chart would be active (hover color, tooltip shown) when the user hovered over the corresponding legend item. That code looked like this:

```
 var " + ClientID + @" = new Chart(" + ClientID + @"CTX, {
    data: { ... },
    options: {
        legend: {
            onHover: function(evt, legendItem) {
                var index = " + ClientID + @".data.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
                if (" + ClientID + @".data.datasets[0].data[index] > 0) {
                    var metaData = " + ClientID + @".getDatasetMeta(0);
                    var activeSegment = metaData.data[index];
                    " + ClientID + @".tooltipActive = [activeSegment];
                    " + ClientID + @".active = [activeSegment];
                }                                   
            },
        }
    }
});
```

Looking through the Chart.js file and documentation, it looks like the `tooltipActive` property has been completely removed, thus breaking the legend hover functionality. I looked through the release notes and PRs on the [Chart.js git](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases) but couldn't find where this was noted as a breaking change, or any mention of it whatsoever. I have to upgrade versions of Chart.js for a separate change I'm making, so reverting back to `v2.3` is not an option. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Did you try v2.5.0? You can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486591/chart-js-polar-area-legend-hover-style-and-margin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on your approach that works with the current version of Chart.js (2.9.3).

Beside `onHover`, you also have to defined an `onLeave` callback function. This makes sure to hide the tooltip and revert the hover effect as soon as the mouse pointer leaves the legend label.

```js
const chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [4, 5, 3],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBorderWidth: 3
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      onHover: (evt, legendItem) => {
        const index = chart.data.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
        const activeSegment = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
        activeSegment._model.backgroundColor = activeSegment._options.hoverBackgroundColor;
        activeSegment._model.borderWidth = activeSegment._options.hoverBorderWidth;
        chart.tooltip._active = [activeSegment];
        chart.tooltip.update();
        chart.draw();
      },
      onLeave: (evt, legendItem) => {
        const index = chart.data.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
        const activeSegment = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
        activeSegment._model.backgroundColor = activeSegment._options.backgroundColor;
        activeSegment._model.borderWidth = activeSegment._options.borderWidth; 
        chart.tooltip._active = [];
        chart.tooltip.update();
        chart.draw();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781749/2358409) from [timclutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775731/timclutton) that works with the current version of Chart.js (2.9.3).

```js
const chart = new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [4, 5, 3],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBorderWidth: 3
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      onHover: (evt, legendItem) => {
        const index = chart.data.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
        const rect = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const point = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index].getCenterPoint();
        const e = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
          clientX: rect.left + point.x,
          clientY: rect.top + point.y
        });
        chart.canvas.dispatchEvent(e);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="80"></canvas>
```