# How to show tooltip on legend hover?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, tooltip, legend, onhover

I am using chart.js in React.

I have read and implemented:
[Chart.js - show tooltip when hovering on legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569325/chart-js-show-tooltip-when-hovering-on-legend?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Unfortunately, this is not providing the desired results. I believe this is because this is being implemented in javascript, and I am implementing react. Not sure if that is impacting anything.

```
const data = {
    labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [4, 5, 3],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)'],
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBorderWidth: 3
    }]
  };
```

```
  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onHover: (evt: any, legendItem: any, legend: any) => {
          const index = legend.chart.data.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
          const activeSegment = legend.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
          // console.log(activeSegment);
          // activeSegment.options.backgroundColor = activeSegment._options.hoverBackgroundColor;
          // activeSegment.options.borderWidth = activeSegment._options.hoverBorderWidth;
          legend.chart.tooltip._active = [activeSegment];
          legend.chart.update();
          legend.chart.draw();
        },
        onLeave: (evt: any, legendItem: any, legend: any) => {
          const index = legend.chart.data.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
          // const activeSegment = legend.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[index];
          // activeSegment.options.backgroundColor = activeSegment._options.backgroundColor;
          // activeSegment.options.borderWidth = activeSegment._options.borderWidth;
          legend.chart.tooltip._active = [];
          legend.chart.update();
          legend.chart.draw();
        }
      },
    },

  }
```

with the end of this component returning the following:

```
return <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />;
```

This produces the chart that is shown in the stackoverflow post that I linked.

Comment: what library / package did you use to render chart react-chartjs-2 or chart.js ?

Comment: react-chart-js-2 @monesul haque

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For v3 you can use an method to set the tooltip programatically

```js
 onHover: (evt, item, legend) => {
          const chart = legend.chart;
          const tooltip = chart.tooltip;

          const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
          tooltip.setActiveElements([{
            datasetIndex: 0,
            index: item.index,
          }], {
            x: (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2,
            y: (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2,
          });


          chart.update();
        },
```

Comment: this solves the problem of displaying the tooltip when I hover over a legend label, however I cannot hover over between labels quickly. Do you know a possible solution to this?

For instance, hovering over One and quickly switching to Two in the legend will cause the Two tooltip not to appear.